# Best way to use modules in NodeJS methods vs global

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, scope, ecmascript-6

I am trying to understand and find out the better way to use modules in node js that are imported via require.

Here are two possible ways I've found.

```
class BookManager {
    constructor() {
        this._validator = require('validator');
        this._BookModel = require('api/book').BookModel;
        this.createNewBook = this.createNewBook.bind(this);
    }
}
```

And

```
const validator = require('validator');
const BookModel = require('api/book').BookModel;
class BookManager {
    constructor() {
        this.createNewBook = this.createNewBook.bind(this);
    }
}
```

In the first case we are encapsulating all neccessary objects as members of the class. From my previous experience working with other languages, this could probably replaced with the dependency injection via constructor.

But encapsulating a class definition seems a bit weird for me. So it could also be like that

```
const BookModel = require('api/book').BookModel;
class BookManager {
    constructor() {
        this._validator = require('validator');
        this.createNewBook = this.createNewBook.bind(this);
    }
}
```

But I am not sure in case of Node JS which way is preferable and why.

Could someone explain the differences, especially about scopes.

thanks.

Comment: Why would you add an entire module for every `BookManager` object?

Comment: Unless you require to be able to inject different modules into every `BookManager` *instance* separately, there's no reason to put them in the class definition.

Comment: Notice that your `const`s are not global, they're in the module scope.